# Zone index number appearing above Web Parts?

Tags: web-part

It would appear that for each web part displayed on only one particular page in my Sharepoint configuration, that the 'Zone Index' is appearing above each web part as seen here:

[image: Sharepoint Zone Issue]

...and here:

[image]

This very well could be some other property, however 'Zone Index' was the only property I saw that seemed to correspond with the numbers I was seeing. These started showing up after I made a title change to one of the Web Parts and I am not really sure why. Any light that can be shed on this would make life as the 'Sharepoint Guy' a little easier :)

Thanks everyone,

MrS1ck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the titles aren't being used in your scenario, the web part Chrome can be set to None.

Answer (score 1):

When multiple web parts exist with the same name, they get the number at the end. Changing the title to something unique will fix it.

If you are trying to remove title you can change the Chrome Type to "None" or "Border Only".
[image: Chrome Type]

Comment: Or since the titles aren't being used, the web part Chrome can be set to None.

Comment: @PirateEric , that was the answer. Would you like to add that as an answer for me so I can give you credit? Thanks!

Comment: Good Catch @PirateEric. Technically my answer answers the question OP asked. I will update mine as well.

Comment: And marked as answer since you were first! Thanks for the help you two